# Как с использованием {} переименовать несколько файлов в linux?

Tags: linux

Задача состоит в следующем. Есть директория, например dir1. В этой директории лежат файлы file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt,file4.txt. Надо переименовать эти файлы ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО с использованием {}, например в file1.pdf, file2, newfile3.txt, file.doc. Не знаю, как это сделать. Могу создать эти файлы с помощью {}, но вот переименовать не могу.

Важное: Обязательно с использованием {} и новые имена файлов не одинаковые.

Comment: А что вы понимаете под использованием `{}`?

Comment: Ну вот здесь например написано как они используются. http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/consol/brace-ru.html  Что то вроде этого...

Comment: Ага, т.е. вопрос всё таки про shell (и скорее всего bash)…

Comment: `$ mv dir1/{file1.txt,newfile1.pdf}` — что сложного-то?